# Mostrar valores de textbox generados dinamicamente javascript

Tags: javascript

No puedo mostrar el contenido de los `inputs` que genero con un botón, alguna idea de como hacerlo? Adjunto código completo, como se puede observar, tengo una función la cual extraigo  el `ID` del `input` que se encuentra en el formulario mediante un bucle, ahí mismo creo los `inputs` adicionales y en si la página funciona bien, al oprimir el botón agregar campos o borrar campos, puede agregar o eliminar los `inputs` sin ningún problema pero al oprimir el botón *Mostrar* datos no puedo mostrar el contenido de los `inputs` que estoy creando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">  
var newsInputs = 0;
function ImprimeDatos(){                                
var correow = document.formaDatos.equipo.value;
    //document.write('<p>Correo: '+ correow + '</p> <BR>');     
    document.write('resultado ' + newsInputs)                       
                    //document.write('<a href="mailto:' + correow + '?body=' + fila1 + '">Enviar mensaje de correo </a>');   
        }

function addMatch(){
var puntero = document.getElementById('tableMatchs'); //recogemos donde van a ir los nuevos campos
newNode = document.createElement('tr'); //creamos un elemento TR para poder agregar TD's
total = 1; //definimos cuantos inputs queremos insertar de un tiron
newsInputs++;
newNode.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));       // creamos un td dentro de newNode
newNode.lastChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Campo '+(total+newsInputs)));

for(i=0;i<total;i++){
    var num_equipo = document.getElementsByName('equipo').length; //recogemos el total de campos equipo que hay para asignar los nuevos ID's
            newNode.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));       // creamos un td dentro de newNode

    var newField = document.createElement('input'); //creamos un elemento input
    newField.name = 'equipo'; //le asignamos un nombre al input creado        
    var newEquipo = num_equipo + 1; // incrementamos el total de campos equipos para poder obtener un ID correlativo.
    newField.id = 'equipo'+newEquipo; //asignamos el nuevo ID al nuevo INPUT        
    newNode.lastChild.appendChild(newField); //le indicamos de quien va a ser hijo.        
inicio=document.getElementById('nextMatch');
    puntero.insertBefore(newNode,inicio);    //insertamos todos justo encima del tr con id nextMatch, almacenado en puntero.    
}

if(newsInputs==1){//añadimos el link de borrar último partido
    newClose = document.createElement('a');
    newClose.id='delPartido';
    newClose.href='javascript:delMatch()';
    newClose.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Borrar último'));
    document.getElementById('controlMatch').appendChild(newClose);
}
centrarContenido();//centramos el contenido de los TD's para que queden bien alineados
}

function centrarContenido(){
var y = document.getElementById('tableMatchs').rows;
for(a=0;a<y.length;a++){
    y[a].align='center';
}
}

function delMatch(){
var total = document.getElementById('tableMatchs').getElementsByTagName("tr").length-2;
separador = document.getElementById("tableMatchs");
separador.removeChild(separador.getElementsByTagName('tr')[total]);
newsInputs --;
if (newsInputs==0){
    //retirar el código para borrar la última dirección de mail
    document.getElementById("controlMatch").removeChild(document.getElementById("delPartido"));
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" name = "formaDatos">
<table border="0" width="380" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
<tbody id="tableMatchs">
 <tr>
    <td width="40">Campo 1</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="equipo" id="equipo"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="nextMatch">
    <td><img src="clear_pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
    <td><img src="clear_pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
    <td><img src="clear_pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
    <td><img src="clear_pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="ImprimeDatos()">Muestra los datos</button>
<table border="0" width="380" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td><center id="controlMatch"><a href="javascript:addMatch();">agregar campo</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</center></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cree otro input para que vieras el ejemplo porque al apretar tu link no crea otro campo, lo que puedes utilizar es `document.querySelectorAll()` el cuál te va a traer un array de lo que selecciones en este caso entro a la tabla con su id `#tableMatchs` después selecciono todos los input que sean de tipo texto, de esta forma `input[type="text"]`, y solamente recorro con un `forEach` y selecciono el valor que tenga cada input, espero te funcione. :D

```js
var newsInputs = 0;
function ImprimeDatos(){                                
var correow = document.querySelectorAll('#tableMatchs input[type="text"]');
    //document.write('<p>Correo: '+ correow + '</p> <BR>');
    correow.forEach(function(input){
      document.write(input.value+' ');
    });                   
                    //document.write('<a href="mailto:' + correow + '?body=' + fila1 + '">Enviar mensaje de correo </a>');   
        }

function addMatch(){
var puntero = document.getElementById('tableMatchs'); //recogemos donde van a ir los nuevos campos
newNode = document.createElement('tr'); //creamos un elemento TR para poder agregar TD's
total = 1; //definimos cuantos inputs queremos insertar de un tiron
newsInputs++;
newNode.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));       // creamos un td dentro de newNode
newNode.lastChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Campo '+(total+newsInputs)));

for(i=0;i<total;i++){
    var num_equipo = document.getElementsByName('equipo').length; //recogemos el total de campos equipo que hay para asignar los nuevos ID's
            newNode.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));       // creamos un td dentro de newNode

    var newField = document.createElement('input'); //creamos un elemento input
    newField.name = 'equipo'; //le asignamos un nombre al input creado        
    var newEquipo = num_equipo + 1; // incrementamos el total de campos equipos para poder obtener un ID correlativo.
    newField.id = 'equipo'+newEquipo; //asignamos el nuevo ID al nuevo INPUT        
    newNode.lastChild.appendChild(newField); //le indicamos de quien va a ser hijo.        
inicio=document.getElementById('nextMatch');
    puntero.insertBefore(newNode,inicio);    //insertamos todos justo encima del tr con id nextMatch, almacenado en puntero.    
}

if(newsInputs==1){//añadimos el link de borrar último partido
    newClose = document.createElement('a');
    newClose.id='delPartido';
    newClose.href='javascript:delMatch()';
    newClose.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Borrar último'));
    document.getElementById('controlMatch').appendChild(newClose);
}
centrarContenido();//centramos el contenido de los TD's para que queden bien alineados
}

function centrarContenido(){
var y = document.getElementById('tableMatchs').rows;
for(a=0;a<y.length;a++){
    y[a].align='center';
}
}

function delMatch(){
var total = document.getElementById('tableMatchs').getElementsByTagName("tr").length-2;
separador = document.getElementById("tableMatchs");
separador.removeChild(separador.getElementsByTagName('tr')[total]);
newsInputs --;
if (newsInputs==0){
    //retirar el código para borrar la última dirección de mail
    document.getElementById("controlMatch").removeChild(document.getElementById("delPartido"));
}
}
```

```html
 <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" name = "formaDatos">
<table border="0" width="380" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
<tbody id="tableMatchs">
 <tr>
    <td width="40">Campo 1</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="equipo" id="equipo"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="equipo" id="equipo"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="nextMatch">
    <td><img src="clear_pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
    <td><img src="clear_pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
    <td><img src="clear_pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
    <td><img src="clear_pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="ImprimeDatos()">Muestra los datos</button>
<table border="0" width="380" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td><center id="controlMatch"><a href="javascript:addMatch();">agregar campo</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</center></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Vick, intentare lo que me dices... Saludos :D

Comment: De nada Pablo, si te fue de ayuda marca la respuesta como aceptada :D, buena tarde compañero! :D